# How to make switching statements based on NSString more efficient and scalable?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a lot of switching statements based on the string value of a button (e.g. moving  arrow Images to the coordinates of a UIButton). I realize that there is a lot of repetition in my code. One thing I thought about was e.g. to use the actual "switch" function but unfortunately it only uses int as switching variable type not strings.

Here's a code example I am looking for to improve:

```
-(void)initAperture{

//Set
if ([[[self dataObject] logAperture] isEqualToString:@"dark"]) {
    [self moveImageView:selectorAperture
              toUIButton:buttonApertureDark
               animated:NO];
} 
if ([[[self dataObject] logAperture] isEqualToString:@"cloudy"]) {
    [self moveImageView:selectorAperture
             toUIButton:buttonApertureCloudy
               animated:NO];
} 
if ([[[self dataObject] logAperture] isEqualToString:@"sunny"]) {
    [self moveImageView:selectorAperture
              toUIButton:buttonApertureSunny
               animated:NO];        
} 
if ([[[self dataObject] logAperture] isEqualToString:@"pinhole"]) {
    [self moveImageView:selectorAperture
              toUIButton:buttonAperturePinhole
               animated:NO];
} 

}
```

Any improvement advice or best-practice is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `NSDictionary` where your keys are these `NSString` objects and your objects are the `UIButton` objects.

Then replace your `if` logic with:

```
[self moveImageView:selectorAperture toUIButton:[_myDictionary objectForKey:[[self dataObject] logAperture] animated:NO]];
```

I just typed that off the tip of my fingers so I'm not sure it'll compile...but I think my example is "good enough".